# Why isn't typescript recognizing my type extensions?

Tags: node.js, typescript

Typescript should be able to tell which extension of a type you are dealing with based on its properties using switch case.

Here are my types:

```
export enum MessageType {
    CallEnd = "CallEnd",
    L2Measurement = "L2Measurement",
}

export type TraceMessages = {
    messageType: MessageType;
};

export interface TraceMessageL2Measurement extends TraceMessages {
    messageType: MessageType.L2Measurement;
    l2Measurement: L2MeasurementMessage;
}

export interface TraceMessageCallEnd extends TraceMessages {
    messageType: MessageType.CallEnd;
    callEnd: CallEndMessage;
}

export type TraceMessage =
    | TraceMessages
    | TraceMessageCallEnd
    | TraceMessageL2Measurement;
```

Now, with a switch case structure like:

```
switch (l2message.messageType) {
    case MessageType.L2Measurement:
        // Typescript should now know that l2message: TraceMessageL2Measurement
```

But Typescript does not understand this, and only offers the base type's (TraceMessages') properties. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share the whole code, some types are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to exclude `TraceMessages` from definition of `TraceMessage`:

```js
export type TraceMessage =
  | TraceMessageCallEnd
  | TraceMessageL2Measurement;
```

Otherwise TypeScript can't get rid of the possibility of `l2message` being a `TraceMessage` with `messageType: "L2Measurement"`, which do not have the `l2Measurement` property.